# How to detect the key binding for a function in elisp?

Tags: key-bindings, help

How would I go about getting the key binding for a function in elisp?

I'd like to know which key is used to quit. e.g. `keyboard-quit`.

I tried using the function used by help functionality but it's not working.

```lisp
(require 'help-fns)
(message "%S" (help-fns--key-bindings (quote keyboard-quit)))
```

However I get the error `Symbol’s value as variable is void: keyboard-quit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun foo (function &optional descriptionp)
  (unless (commandp function) (error "Not a command: %s" function))
  (let* ((key   (car (where-is-internal
                      (or (command-remapping function) function)
                      overriding-local-map nil nil)))
         (desc  (and descriptionp  (key-description key))))
    (or desc  key)))

(foo 'keyboard-quit)   ; [7]
(foo 'keyboard-quit t) ; "C-g"
```

Function `help-fns--key-bindings` is intended to be used in a particular context, which is not available or relevant here.

Comment: This returns `""` when `descriptionp` is `t` and the key is not found, returning nil in this case is probably more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substitute-command-keys`, e.g.,

```lisp
(substitute-command-keys "\\[keyboard-quit]")
;; => "C-g"
```

though if there are multiple key bindings, it returns only one of them (the "first" one), for example,

```lisp
(substitute-command-keys "\\[kmacro-start-macro]")
;; => "C-x ("
```

see also it's docstring and [(elisp) Keys in Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keys-in-Documentation.html).

Comment: Works well, ended up using this answer however the other answer more closely matches the question since it takes a function.